# WordPress sidebar inside get category id and get current post row number

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `newspaper7` theme for WordPress and have inside `td_module_mx16` the following code:

```
<?php


class td_module_mx16 extends td_module {

    function __construct($post) {
        //run the parrent constructor
        parent::__construct($post);
    }

    function render() {
        ob_start();

        ?>

        <div class="<?php echo $this->get_module_classes();?>">
            <div class="meta-info-container ">

                <div class="td-info-container">
                    <div class="td-module-image">
                        <?php echo $this->get_image('td_356x364');?>
                        <?php if (td_util::get_option('tds_category_module_mx16') == 'yes') { echo $this->get_category(); }?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="td-item-details">
                        <div class="td-module-meta-info  ">
                            <?php echo $this->get_date();?>

                            <? // php echo $this->get_category();?>
                            <?php echo $this->get_comments();?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="td-excerpt">
                             <?php echo $this->get_title(); 

        ?>

                                 <?php // echo $this->get_excerpt();?>
                        </div>
<?
        /*
                        <div class="td-read-more">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->href;?>"><?php echo __td('Read more', TD_THEME_NAME);?></a>
                        </div>
                        */
        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

In this file inside I want to get:

- CATEGORY ID for each listing post
- AND ROW number for each post like (title near 1,2,3,4,5)

Any idea?

Comment: Is this module is in loop ?

Comment: @Mohammaad i dont know , i know just sidebar in right side

Comment: where do you want the category id and row number?

Comment: @mouhammed row number for near to title category id i need title near , i will manually add after spesific images with category id ty

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli row number for near to title category id i need title near , i will manually add after spesific images with category id ty